# alfresco create file by http request post CMIS

Tags: alfresco

I use Alfresco Cloud, and I want to create a file (text file for example) in a specified folder.

The documentation is really poor about that and I wanted to know if anyone knows how to do that. All I know is I must use a POST request, but don't know the parameters of the query...

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try reading the [Alfresco Cloud (Public) API Documentation](http://www.alfresco.com/develop/cloud)? Only that looks pretty complete and sufficiently detailed to me!

Comment: It mention only to use "POST" HTTP request for create a file, without mentionning any args or anything more than just "Create entities with POST" ! Great !

Comment: All those sorts of file operations in the public API are just plain old [CMIS](http://cmis.alfresco.com/). You can do that by hand, but it's much much easier if you use a library and let that do all the hard work!

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr ! Incredible but I didn't found this on the website. Unfortunatly, seems chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html is not compatible with alfresco cloud. Also, on specification document, I read that createDocument must have properties attribute as mentionned here http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/os/cmis-spec-v1.0.html#_Toc243905449 but don't really know what is these properties and how to define them on a post request. Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that DotCMIS doesn't work with the Alfresco Cloud instance?

Comment: I get unauthorized on  ISession session = factory.GetRepositories(parameters)[0].CreateSession(); and my username/password is correct. In addition, DotCMIS can't authentificate with access_token ([DotCMIS.SessionParameter don't have header section)

Comment: Can't you just give a special username and the token as the password? Sounds like a different, new question though!

Comment: First, what do you mean by "special username" ? I tried the couple "my_username/my_access_token". No success. Secondly, I just miss how to create a new document. Maybe you can just help me by creating an empty document with a given name with POST REQUEST, because after that i know how to modify it. A week that I'm stuck on this problem... I really don't know what to do for this....

Comment: I think there's a special username that indicates that you're supplying an access token not a username/password, but I can't remember for sure. That's a different question if so. Secondly, you really shouldn't be trying to write your own brand new CMIS client, just re-use and existing one and fix it up if needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem :

```
        String accessToken = "your access token"
        String filename = "FileName";
        String filesummary = "Test file summary";
        String filecontent = "Hello world!";
        String filetype = "text/plain";

        String body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" xmlns:cmisra=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/\" xmlns:cmis=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/\">" 
                    + "<title>" + filename + "</title> " 
                    + "<summary>" + filesummary +"</summary>"
                    + "<content type=\"" + filetype + "\">" + filecontent + "</content>"
                    + "<cmisra:object> <cmis:properties> <cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId=\"cmis:objectTypeId\"><cmis:value>cmis:document</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId> </cmis:properties> </cmisra:object> </entry>";

        byte[] content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.alfresco.com/yoursite.com/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom/children?id=your_folder_id");
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        req.ContentType = "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8"; 
        req.ContentLength = content.Length;
        using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        String responseContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(responseContent);
```